# iPhone App status "Upload Received" for 6 days (144 hours)

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

The 1.1 update of my App got rejected. Then, after making a change I uploaded it using the Application Loader, during uploading the Application Loader froze and I had to kill it myself. Then the status changed to “Upload Received”. So it seems the binary was uploaded anyway.

But now, it has been in “Upload Received” for 6 days (144 hours!). Normally it changes from “Upload Received” to “Waiting for Review” in a couple of minutes. iTunes Connect FAQ: “If your app has been in the Upload Received state for more than 24 hours, you should contact iTunes Connect Support through the iTunes Connect Contact Us system.”. Apple has not responded yet to my contact forms, I’ve used the contract form three times now….

In the meantime, when in status “Upload Received“ you can’t reject binary.

I'm not going to upload it using a different App name / ID, as my reviews and top list positions will be gone...

Any advice? Just wait? Anyone knows how to deal with this situation?

Cheers Jeroen

Comment: Only advice I can give would be to contact support. Since you've already done that, I guess all you can do is wait :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I contacted support by using the contact form using these options: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/4771/screenshots.png

I got an auto-generated acknowledgement message from itunesconnect@apple.com, replying is useless if I have to believe the message "Thank you for contacting iTunes Connect Support.  This is an auto-generated response to your inquiry.  Please do not respond directly to this email.".

First time my App status has been unchanged for 1 week, especially strange in "Upload Received", so I'll reply anyway...

Comment: So whatever happened? I'm concerned because my app update has been "upload received" now for about 12 hours.

Comment: Same for me. Three days. Three questions to Apple. No responses. Still in "Upload Received" state.

Answer (score 21):

FYI, I fixed this by editing the screenshots and re-saved the metadata.

Comment: it was 15 minutes past upload received state. I followed your suggestion and VOILA it di the trick for me as well

Comment: I just add to click 'Metadata and Uploads' edit, and save, to solve it

Comment: It didn't work for me neither, it seems there is some kind of trouble as you just posted 8 minutes ago and I've been waiting for an hour

Comment: FYI : I also had the same issue and talked to itunes support team..they mentioned that is affecting all the developers and they are aware of it and working on it.

Comment: Number to call iTunes Provider support (877) 206-2092

Answer (score 6):

This issue was resolved by Apple on sep 3rd, after calling them (http://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.html). The phone call resulted in swift escalation within Apple.

They resolved it by putting my App in status "Waiting for review". After that, the normal process applied, after a couple of days it changed to "In review" and after 7 days total it changed to "Ready for sale".

So calling Apple would be the best action if the mails just won't get it done. I got some really standard email responses that didn't really indicate they were looking into the matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific selection under contact us for this very issue.  Seems to be common for them to have this under the drop down.  i would use this selection under contact us as it probably goes to a specific person that handles this issue.

Frequently Asked Questions:
Why is my app in Upload Received status for over 24 hours? 
If your app has been delivered successfully but has the Upload Received status for more than 24 hours, there may be an issue with your binary. For additional support, use the Contact Us module.

If your app has been in the status Upload Received for over 24 hours, contact us.